# phpMyAdmin Error #1045

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I am getting the following error when trying to import a CSV file into my database through phpMyAdmin:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'xxxx.xxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

note that xxxx.xxxx is the user name that i have logged in with to phpMyAdmin via my web browser.

This issue began a month ago, when our server host upgraded our version of phpMyAdmin.

We also have phpMyAdmin (for some reason) installed in two different places, and the same error is given in either place.

Would appreciate some help in getting this fixed, as its starting to become a nuisance.

EDIT 1: i tried running the grant privileges request based on the link that was sent as a possible duplicate question, and still was given the same #1045 error.

EDIT 2: this issue only happens when trying to import a csv file using the LOAD DATA function.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: I tried running the following:

grant all privileges on *.* to 'MYUSERNAME'@localhost identified by 'MYPASSWORD' with grant option;

and i was given the same #1045 error.